# Android Compose change tap color

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a basic row in compose.

```
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .background(MaterialTheme.colors.background)
                .clickable { click.invoke() }
        ) {
            Text(
                text = stringResource(id = item.first),
                textAlign = TextAlign.Start,
                color = MaterialTheme.colors.onPrimary,
                modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)
            )
        }
```

When its clicked the color is grey. I would like to change this to a custom color but I can't seem to figure out how.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can provide it with the indication parameter:

```
clickable(
    interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
    indication = rememberRipple(color = Color.Red),
) { }
```

If you want to change it for a group of views, you can provide it with `CompositionLocalProvider` in `LocalIndication`:

```
CompositionLocalProvider(
    LocalIndication provides rememberRipple(color = Color.Red)
) {
    SomeView()
)
```

Or you can embed it in your theme to apply to the whole application:

```
@Composable
fun AppTheme(
    darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(),
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    val colors = if (darkTheme) {
        DarkThemeColors
    } else {
        LightThemeColors
    }
    MaterialTheme(
        colors = colors,
        typography = typography,
        shapes = shapes,
    ) {
        CompositionLocalProvider(
            LocalIndication provides rememberRipple(color = Color.Red),
            content = content,
        ) 
    }
}
```