# Change highlight on clickable Text possible?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose-text

I have a `@Composable Text("Dropbox")` whose `Modifier` also implements a

```
clickable {
    //..
}
```

But when I tapping on it

[image]

, it gets a grey highlight!?

[image]

I do not want this grey hightlight. Can I get rid of this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Compose change tap color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69000799/android-compose-change-tap-color/69000913#69000913)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here `indication` is responsible for showing the highlight.
So making `indication = null` should do the job

```
.clickable(
    onClick = {
        //..
    },
    indication = null,
    interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
)
```